# ListViewItems become blank when enabled NavigationCache and IncrementalUpdateBehavior

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

Here is my code:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick" ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource ButtonBorderThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="0,0,0,3">
                <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,9.5">
                    <TextBlock
                    Text="{Binding Title}"
                    TextWrapping="Wrap"
                    Pivot.SlideInAnimationGroup="1"
                    CommonNavigationTransitionInfo.IsStaggerElement="True"
                    Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}"
                    Margin="0,0,19,0">
                        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <core:IncrementalUpdateBehavior Phase="1"/>    
                        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock
                    Text="{Binding Description}"
                    TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"
                    Pivot.SlideInAnimationGroup="2" 
                    CommonNavigationTransitionInfo.IsStaggerElement="True" 
                    Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemContentTextBlockStyle}"
                    Margin="0,0,19,0">
                        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <core:IncrementalUpdateBehavior Phase="2"/>    
                        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Then, I set `NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required` in code-behind. When I navigate to ItemPage and go back. ListViewItems will become blank when you slide it and never show again. They just disappear like this:

[image: blank listviewitem]

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I find out the problem. It is a bug.

Because in the IncrementalUpdateBehavior, it use a function called "FindContentTemplateRoot" to search the visual tree for associated object's ContentTemplateRoot. When I navigate to another page, it raise associated object's Unloaded event and search the visual tree again. But this time it failed because it parent had been unloaded. VisualTreeHelper.GetParent() returns null.

So, it cause a bug that this Behavior can't normally uncache the associated object. When page goes back, associated object caches again. So that the associated object's opacity and DataContext will set twice or more. It just messed up.

Comment: More relevant discussion can be found here: http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/winphone/wpdevelop.aspx?ID=4304c4e2-8b5f-406f-8c16-511453e45325